# How to get all products without Context Prestashop

Tags: php, cron, prestashop

I'm trying to do a cron script for automatize my module and I'm getting few errors with Prestashop 1.6 Core.

I want to retrieve all products from the shop with core functions. In Prestashop backoffice is working fine but when I want to use it executing the cron only I'm getting an error with the context: "Trying to get property of non-object"

My function to retrieve all products is this:

```
    public static function getAllProducts() {
    $lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
    return (Product::getProducts($lang, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'DESC', false, false, null));
}
```

And my cron_script.php is this:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
require_once('mymodule.php');

$products = MyModule::getAllProducts();
```

It exists any method for retrieve all products  without the context and without using SQL statements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  return (Product::getProducts($lang, 0, 0, 'id_product', 'DESC');
```

Regards

Comment: The first line of this function is `if (!$context) {$context = Context::getContext();}` so it will need and use the context data.

Comment: That's true. I was trying with default values and nothing